# How to handle webhooks in flutter

Tags: flutter, webhooks

I am new to webhooks, i understand the concept of how it works and its use, but how do i handle it in flutter or any software,since the response is not sent back to the client app but to the server side, what exactly should i be doing to get that response.

p.s i am working on the twitter api, and need to authenticate the user, the api sends the response to a webhook, i have tried Flutter_web_auth_2 but crashes if you have twitter installed, hence i want to implement it myself.

Thank you.